# Search and modify using sed in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to edit a postgres configuration file using script

I would like to search if

`listen_addresses = '*'` 
already present  or not. If already present, do nothing and if the exact string is not present, add the entry  using following rule

If there is any configuration line with `listen_addresses` but with any other value that '*' exists, then I need to comment the line with a comment
 `Commented out on DD-MM-YYYY by XYZ` 
and then add a new line 
`listen_addresses = '*'`
  followed by  a comment

```
Added on DD-MM-YYYY by XYZ
```

What I tried is some thing like this:

```
sed -i 's/^#?listen_addresses .*/listen_addresses = '*'/'  /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
```

But that do not help adding the comments and will insert only
`listen_addresses = *` due to missing escape characters.

I could not figure out how to accomplish this change.

Comment: sed is used as a search & replace tool. What you put in the 'replace' string is upto you. Put the comment as part of replace string. You can use `\n` for newline.

Comment: Edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If it doesn't exist, you want to start by commenting it out? Sounds like a contradiction, but eh.
- *Any line starting with listen_addresses with any other value* - Matching "[this] *not followed by* [that]" needs a negative lookahead, which `sed` regexes don't support.
- `sed` processes line by line, which makes it difficult to search the entire file and then decide whether to make changes.

This will be much easier if you either:

a) Comment out *every* `listen_address =` line, regardless of whether it's correct, then always add a new one to the end of the file:

```
sed -i "s/^\(listen_addresses .*\)/# Commented out by Name YYYY-MM-DD \1/" postgresql.conf
echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> postgresql.conf
```

That would get annoying if you run this script regularly, as the file would grow and grow forever.

or

b) Use tools other than `sed`. But you haven't said you have any other tools available. Grep would make it easier, Perl even easier. But sticking with sed  (and bash), what about a variation on the above:

```
# Comment out every listen_address line:
sed -i "s/^\(listen_addresses .*\)/#\1 Commented out by Name YYYY-MM-DD/" postgresql.conf

# Try to uncomment a correct one:
sed -i "s/^#\(listen_addresses = '\*'\).*/\1/" postgresql.conf

# Check if the correct one exists, and if it doesn't, add it:
if ! sed -n -e "/^listen_addresses = '\*'/!ba;Q0;:a;\$Q1" postgresql.conf ; then
  echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> postgresql.conf
fi
```

### Edit

OK, the constrained sed only was fun, but this is more straightforward logic and adds the new line just after a commented one.

```
#!/bin/env bash

if grep -q "^listen_addresses = '\*'" postgresql.conf ; then
    echo "Correct listen_addresses found, doing nothing"
    exit
fi

if ! grep -q "^listen_addresses =.*" postgresql.conf ; then
    echo "No listen_addresses found, adding one at the end"
    echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> postgresql.conf
    exit
fi

if grep -q "^listen_addresses =.*" postgresql.conf ; then
    echo "Wrong listen_addresses found, commenting them out"
    sed -i "s/^\(listen_addresses.*\)/#\1 Commented out by Name YYYY-MM-DD/" postgresql.conf

    echo "Adding correct one"
    sed -i "/^#listen_addresses/a listen_addresses = '\*'" postgresql.conf
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. These looks enough, let me try them and give you feedback. I edited the question for more clarity (trouble with English as non native language).   For me grep was fine along with sed, but perl looks pretty tough for me master at this time. I should look at them.

Comment: This worked. I will improve my scripting skils. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I would have loved to insert new configuration string next to the commented line if it exists.

Comment: @Jamess That would be neat. I've edited with another version that does add the line after the commented one (and uses grep, doesn't use the sed extended codes, and tells you what it's doing)

Answer (score 2):

In shell you cannot nest single quote inside single quotes. Also use double quote for using shell variables in sed.

Try this sed:

```
comment="commented on $(date)"
sed -i "s~^#?listen_addresses .*~listen_addresses = '*'\n$comment~" /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
```